# Graylog2 web interface doesn't show logs/messages even though the data is in Elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, graylog2

So, I have installed Graylog2, Elasticsearch and MongoDB.

All of them are running on same machine. The thing is log collection is working, which I can verify by querying Elasticsearch but Graylog2 web interface doesn't show any messages.

Here is web interface log:

```
2015-08-26 15:17:29,195 - [DEBUG] - from application in main
Loading timeout value into cache from configuration for key DEFAULT: Not configured, falling back to default.

2015-08-26 15:17:29,519 - [DEBUG] - from application in main
Loading timeout value into cache from configuration for key node_refresh: Not configured, falling back to default.

2015-08-26 15:17:29,727 - [INFO] - from play in main
Application started (Prod)

2015-08-26 15:17:29,754 - [INFO] - from play in main
Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000

2015-08-26 15:17:36,936 - [DEBUG] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
Loading timeout value into cache from configuration for key sources_all: Not configured, falling back to default.
```

Nothing unusual there. Here is Graylog2-server log:

```
2015-08-26 15:11:53,639 INFO : org.graylog2.periodical.Periodicals - Starting [org.graylog2.periodical.IndexRetentionThread] periodical in [0s], polling every [300s].
2015-08-26 15:11:53,641 INFO : org.graylog2.initializers.Initializers - Initialized initializer <org.graylog2.initializers.PeriodicalsInitializer>.
2015-08-26 15:11:53,641 INFO : org.graylog2.outputs.OutputRegistry - Initialized output <org.graylog2.outputs.BatchedElasticSearchOutput>.
2015-08-26 15:11:53,669 INFO : org.graylog2.inputs.InputRegistry - Starting [org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput] input with ID <55dd7d6be4b0ef26379cf956>
2015-08-26 15:11:53,689 INFO : org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput - Started syslog UDP input server on /144.76.34.175:514
2015-08-26 15:11:53,692 INFO : org.graylog2.inputs.InputRegistry - Completed starting [org.graylog2.inputs.syslog.udp.SyslogUDPInput] input with ID <55dd7d6be4b0ef26379cf956>
2015-08-26 15:11:55,046 INFO : org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler - Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.5 2013-12-18 14:27:29...
2015-08-26 15:11:56,033 INFO : org.graylog2.Core - Started REST API at <http://127.0.0.1:12900/>
2015-08-26 15:11:56,034 INFO : org.graylog2.Main - Graylog2 up and running.
2015-08-26 15:17:32,674 INFO : org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager - Enabling session validation scheduler...
```

Nothing unusual there either. But it doesn't display the data in front end.
[image: See screenshot]

And at the right, it displays total events however.

I can't find any similar issues being discussed on internet.

I am using Graylog2 0.20.2 and Elasticsearch 0.90.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just found out, when I select 'All' from dropdown options, all data is displayed.

Looks like this was rather a timezone issue. So, there is no issue with installation.